# Masspay paypal option to get ipn response through URL not from paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, masspay

Is there an option in Paypal Masspay to get notifications about transactions like IPN response through API URL, and not from  the Paypal account.

Comment: I am using paypal-adaptive-payment and masspay for multiple payment at one time, I found an option of IPN_response to set notify in paypal account but I already set there other site URL there, I search for is their any option like simple payment where we can pass our ipn-URL for update status in DB in API URL.

Comment: No one commented on it??